# Vue CLI installation leaves multiple warnings and does not work on Mac OS

Tags: node.js, macos, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I use a 2017 MacBook Pro with Catalina (10.15.3) and have installed the latest version of node (v12.18.3) and npm (6.14.6) yet when I run the command `npm install -g @vue/cli`, I get the following message:

```
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
/Users/MYUSERNAME/npm/bin/vue -> /Users/MYUSERNAME/npm/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
npm WARN @vue/compiler-sfc@3.0.0-rc.7 requires a peer of vue@3.0.0-rc.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ @vue/cli@4.5.4
added 3 packages from 2 contributors and updated 2 packages in 95.885s
```

After this, when I run `vue --version` I get the message `-bash: vue: command not found`

I have read through many forums and tried various ways of installing, using `sudo`, running `sudo chown -R MYUSERNAME:/usr/local/lib/node_modules` before trying again, `npm install -g @vue/cli@latest` etc; and i've even completely uninstalled and reinstalled node and npm but nothing works

What should I do?

Comment: Those warnings are normal. Did you restart bash after installing?

Comment: Yes please. I restarted but the issue still persists. How much the "vue --version" does not work though?

Comment: I think you don't have updated version of npm so `Npm install -g npm@latest` then `npm install` after doing this try to install vue.js `Npm i -g @vue/cli`

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of frustration, This helped me resolve it:

[How to fix the terminal error: vue command not found (MacOS)](https://medium.com/@markfasel/how-to-fix-the-terminal-error-vue-command-not-found-macos-4c569875d888)

Tip: You can also go to the Home Finder window of your user account, and view hidden folders (Command + Shift + . ) and edit the .bash_profile with a text editor to follow the advice in the article. Look for the '$username -> npm -> bin' folder, inside you should see a vue.js file. This is the folder that vue-cli is installed into

Answer (score 0):

The "Current" version of Node (v15.0.1) and npm v7.0.5 allows for successful installation of `@vue/cli` on macOS Catalina.

Download the latest "Current" `macOS Installer (.pkg)` from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) and try that. If you use `nvm`, add the following code to either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

Note: On Catalina, the default shell is `zsh`, so you would add the following to `.zshrc`.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error it will show if you don't have the proper version of npm

so `Npm install -g npm@latest`
then `npm install`

after doing this try to install vue.js `Npm i -g @vue/cli`